# Dynamically replace SQL string with parameters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

Has anyone tried to dynamically turn a standard sql string into a parameterized query?  In other words, I need to change this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = 'Adams'
```

to this:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = @name
```

I've started to work with the Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom.Sql and Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom assemblies, but before I bear down on it, I was wondering if there is something already out in the wild that would do this.

Comment: I've never seen it before.  What exactly are you trying to do that would require this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server does this under the covers (and tools like [ClearTrace](http://www.scalesql.com/cleartrace/default.aspx)).

One way is to use a regular expression to normalise (not exactly what you are looking for) such as this SQL CLR method based on work done by Itzik Ben-Gan and modified by Adam Machanic:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
public static SqlString sqlsig(SqlString querystring)
{
    return (SqlString)Regex.Replace(
       querystring.Value,
       @"([\s,(=<>!](?![^\]]+[\]]))(?:(?:(?:(?:(?# expression coming
       )(?:([N])?(')(?:[^']'')*('))(?# character
       )(?:0x[\da-fA-F]*)(?# binary
       )(?:[-+]?(?:(?:[\d]*\.[\d]*[\d]+)(?# precise number
       )(?:[eE]?[\d]*)))(?# imprecise number
       )(?:[~]?[-+]?(?:[\d]+))(?# integer
       )(?:[nN][uU][lL][lL])(?# null
       ))(?:[\s]?[\+\-\*\/\%\&\\^][\s]?)?)+(?# operators
       )))",
       @"$1$2$3#$4");
}
```

but accuracy of output may not catch every possible parameterisable phrase.

I'm curious as to why you need this?

Update: As Martin mentioned, there is also the [RML Utilities for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=7EDFA95A-A32F-440F-A3A8-5160C8DBE926&displaylang=en)

[Description of the Replay Markup Language (RML) Utilities for SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944837)

Comment: +1 I think RML Utilities does this as well but I'm not sure whether it requires a trace file to work off.

Comment: @Martin: Yup. Mentioned them here: http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2008/08/determining-poorly-performing-queries.html

Comment: This is a backend for a site that is completely data driven instead of code driven - ie: there are no objects per se in our code, the objects are built up into JSON via a metadata layer that retrieves the schema from database/caching layer.  Interesting about RML - never heard of that.  Its not what I need for this case, but its nice to know its out there.

Comment: I was ultimately able to do this via Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom rather easily but you had an interesting answer - and the regex is scary looking ;) so I am marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well my knee jerk reaction for someone doing string searches/manipulation would be to use a regex to search/replace.

The hard part becomes determining what you replace with?  a parameter called `@Adam` seems pretty weird and i'm not sure how you would know you want to replace it with `@Name`.

Can you describe what your end goals is?  There may be a better way to do this...

Comment: I actually need to parse the string and parameterize it but I also need to map back the columns to a metadata layer that applies the proper validation and column names, etc.

Comment: I was able to get Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom to work.  Once I've cleaned it up, I'll post the code back for future ref.

Comment: @HostDude - please do. Sounds interesting.

Comment: I decided to bag it using the scriptdom.  Not sure if it was something I was doing, but it was very very slow (200+ ms) to evaluate simple strings.  I wound up using the Gold Parser which already has a SQL syntax - http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/.  Overkill for simple strings, but we needed it in other parts of our app anyway.